# Next.js SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: api, next.js

When I try to call an API in Next.js I get the following error:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Heres my Code:

```js
const callAPI = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(
                `http://localhost:8000/api/clients`
            );
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
```

And the API looks like this:

[image]

It works with other APIs I've tried but not this one, is there something I am missing?

Comment: Please post the **exact** result string of your API (check in developer tools, network inspector). Obviously it's not valid json ...

Comment: Post the raw json response and not the formatted one/screenshot.

Comment: Well, your request returns an 500 internal Server error status code. Chances are high, there is no valid JSON in your response